# heatmap in R without change of order

Tags: heatmap

I want to use R to plot a heatmap of a matrix like the following and don't want the order of row names and column names changed. Neither do I need the dendrogram. I would expect in the heatmap where the diagonal is all zero but the resulting heatmap shows a different pattern. Can anyone help me?

> mat <- matrix(c(0, 2, 3,
> 2, 0, 3,
> 3, 3, 0),
> nrow = 3,
> byrow = TRUE)
>
> rownames(mat) <- c("t1", "t2", "t3") colnames(mat) <- c("t1", "t2", "t3")
>
> heatmap(mat, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = terrain.colors(20))

[unexpected heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm3Zm.png)